# Why connected node count have dropped since august 1st?

Tags: nodes, connection, peers, peer-discovery

before 1st august i used to connect to `55+ nodes` on my `bitcoin-core`, even if i kept the bitcoin-core running for 12 hours.

but after `1st of august`, the `connected nodes` count is not going above `15-23`

why is that ?

what changed on `august 1st` ?

i  got that number when i do

```
bitcoin-cli getinfo
```

Answer (score 1):

A common cause for a node's connection count going down and staying down for a while is IP address changes: It can take a while for knowledge of the new address to percolate in the network.

Otherwise, your prior high count could just have easily been caused by an attack or spy-peers that have since stopped.

It's a bit hard to say since the expected number of peers of a listening node depends on how many other peers are in the same /16.